# How to get column/field names in OrmLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, ormlite

I'm defining table/field names thru usual annotations, like:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "M")
public class Headers {
    //android requires primary key as _ID
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "_ID", dataType = DataType.INTEGER_OBJ)
    private Integer id;

    @DatabaseField(
            columnName = "MM2",
            uniqueCombo = true,
            canBeNull = true, //null means root folder
            dataType = DataType.INTEGER_OBJ
    )
    private Integer parentId;
}
```

Meantime somewhere deep in my code, I need to make some queries, like:

```
QueryBuilder<Headers, Integer> qb = headersDao.queryBuilder();
qb.where().eq("_ID",  headerId); //_ID field name
```

This kind of code looks ugly, since field name (in this case `_ID`) is hardcoded (even if would be declared as `final static String`)

**Question:** is it normal OrmLite coding practice? I'd be expecting that I could use instead of hardcoded `_ID` field some small code. For sure OrmLite "knows" all field names. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a constant for the field name, like

```
private static final String FIELD_ID = "_ID";
// Or make it public as Gray said into comment
public static final String FIELD_ID = "_ID";
```

and use it as like

```
//android requires primary key as _ID
@DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = FIELD_ID, dataType = DataType.INTEGER_OBJ)
private Integer id;
```

And into your query

```
QueryBuilder<Headers, Integer> qb = headersDao.queryBuilder();
qb.where().eq(FIELD_ID,  headerId); //_ID field name
```

---

If you look at [documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/select-arg)

They also follow the same

```
QueryBuilder<Account, String> qb = accountDao.queryBuilder();
Where where = qb.where();
// the name field must be equal to "foo"
where.eq(Account.NAME_FIELD_NAME, "foo");
// and
where.and();
// the password field must be equal to "_secret"
where.eq(Account.PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME, "_secret");
PreparedQuery<Account, String> preparedQuery = qb.prepareQuery();
```

Comment: I suspect you want to make the field name `public` so others can reference it.

Comment: @Gray Hey grey thanks for pointing out that. Yes he can make it public also (if that variable is being used by outside of class also)

Comment: I was hoping for a mapper class equivalent that will have list of tables, column names